# Is it safe to override .hash on an ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

The default ActiveRecord `hash` implementation is to return the hash of the id.

This is great for persisted instances. It's **terrible** for un-persisted instances **especially** because Rails defaults to `BasicObject.==` for ActiveRecord instances with no IDs.

So all unsaved ActiveRecord instances will have the same hash and not be equal. This is a worst-case scenario for performance of putting many un-persisted ActiveRecord instances into a Set.

I did the following on my User class. **Is there some "Rails reason" I shouldn't do this? Is there documentation or a discussion about this?** All of my tests still pass.

```
alias_method :_old_hash, :hash
def hash
  id ? _old_hash : email.hash + api_key.hash
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in rails 4.2.

Specifically, if an activerecord instance has a null id, then object_id.hash is used as the hash value.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How was it fixed?

Comment: I've added the important missing detail.